# How to export a #defines from c++ shared library to application

Tags: c++, linux, makefile, shared-libraries, dllexport

My library is built with some `#define` enabled (e.g `-DUSE_FOO=1`) and also `USE_FOO` is used in public header file. 
The problem is an application using library includes the public header file and thus `USE_FOO` appears in the application context and would be undefined in application context.

How can I export `USE_FOO` define to application based on whether it's enabled in the library or not?

e.g

```
include/public/foo.h
lib/libfoo.so   --> foo.cc

in foo.h contain code as  
#if defined (USE_FOO)
#define SIZE 5
#else
#define SIZE 10
#endif

foo.cc
#include "foo.h"
int getSizeFromLib()
{
 return SIZE;
}
```

`libfoo.so` source file includes `foo.h` and built by configuring `USE_FOO` at compile time.

Now, application uses libfoo library by including `public/foo.h` and uses his own build configuration to build the app. but the problem is application is unaware of `USE_FOO` which will be always undefined in application side. So `SIZE` will be 10 in application but 5 inside the library

I want `USE_FOO` to exported to application based on whether its defined for `libfoo.so` or not. I.e if `libfoo.so` is built with `USE_FOO=1` application should also see `USE_FOO=1` and vice-versa

If it's not possible to do it in pre-defined way, then any trick to solve this would be welcomed.

Comment: A shared library has nothing that resembles #define. You need to handle compilation flags yourself.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux world this task is solved by [pkgconfig](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) tool. Basically in addition to binaries and headers your library also comes with a `.pc` file which looks like

```
prefix=/usr/local
exec_prefix=${prefix}
includedir=${prefix}/include
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib

Name: foo
Description: The foo library
Version: 1.0.0
Cflags: -I${includedir}/foo USE_FOO=1
Libs: -L${libdir} -lfoo
```

This file is installed to `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` and clients should query proper `CFLAGS` from it by calling `pkg-config` from Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Wextra $(pkg-config --cflags)
```

For more details, check the [guide](https://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html).

The only *portable* solution would be to add an *auto-generated* `foo-config.h` header which will be included by all library public headers and would define all version-specific defines (like `USE_FOO`). This would of course only work in source files that actually include library headers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to "export" a preprocessor define from a library to an application. Both must be compiled with compatible flags, for example:

```
CFLAGS=-DUSE_FOO=1
gcc $CFLAGS --shared -o lib/libfoo.so foo.cc
gcc $CFLAGS lib/libfoo.so app.c
```

Comment: "There is no way to export a preprocessor define from a library" - at least on Linux `pkg-config` does this.